# Jquery Transit Not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, transition, jquery-transit

I've been playing around with the jquery plugin Jquery Transit : http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/ but no matter what I do, the code doesn't behave like I expect it to (as a matter of fact, it doesn't behave at all)

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  div {
background-color:yellow;
width:100px;
border:1px solid blue;
position:absolute;
left:50px;
}

</style>
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script scr='jquery.transit.js'></script>
</head>

<title>test</title>
</head><body>
 <button id="go"> Run</button>
<div id="block">Hello!</div>

    <script>
$(function() {
    $("#go").click(
function(){
 $("#block").transition({ x: '90px' }, 1500 );
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The code doesn't work at all. I added the jquery animation code to compare it to, which works perfectly fine. Now I KNOW that jquery 1.8 broke jquery transit, but I'm using jquery 1.7 here so that shouldn't be an issue.

I'm at a loss here, anyone got any ideas?

EDIT:

I've followed everyone's instructions and created this: 
http://web.uvic.ca/~markkoni/
and although the examples seem to work jsfiddle it doesn't work in practice.

Comment: close your click event dispatcher with $(function{ code });

Comment: I've edited my answer, your script tag is not correct.

Comment: Marcin, you typed wrong scr=""  http://i.imgur.com/wbuxm.png Use notepad++ or other IDE that color hilight, so you would see if theres a syntax problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working demo (Tested on **localhost** too): http://jsfiddle.net/fedmich/S2ube/

the minified script seems to be not working. change your code from

```
http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/jquery.transit.min.js
```

to

```
http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/jquery.transit.js
```

also don't directly hotlink the javascript and put it on your own site, because when his site is down later, your web_app will also be down if you use his site's js.

and yes, put your code after pageload

```
$(function() {
    //your code here
});
```

Comment: Sorry I deleted the comment, it's an issue with my network not loading https ressources. Sorry about that.

Comment: ah yes, his site is a bit down too before, hence I adviced not to hotlink from his site

Comment: When I do it on the jsfiddle it works... but when I put to the test it does not for some reason. Here is what I did: http://web.uvic.ca/~markkoni/

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/wbuxm.png  Use notepad++ or other IDE that color hilight, so you would see if theres a syntax problem

Comment: Oh, god, I must be dislexic. Thanks so much!

Comment: No problem, these things happens to all of us before at some time.
Syntax Hilighting can help us with this kind of issues.
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Make sur your DOM is loaded before manipulating it by enclosing it in a [jQuery ready handler](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) :

```
$(function(){
    $('#go').click(function(){
        $("#block").transition({x: '90px'}, 1500);
    });
});​
```

Also, prefer using css `left` property instead of `x` which does not exists.

```
div {    
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
}
```

Here is [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E9GdT/)

Also make sure your script tag looks like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Instead of

```
<script>
```

**Notes :**

I'm using [**jQuery 1.7.2**](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js) in my fiddle, it seems that [transit is not compatible with transit.js](https://github.com/rstacruz/jquery.transit/pull/77) yet.

Answer (score 1):

Transit does support backgroundColor and color properties. Check out the example : http://jsfiddle.net/PAnCh/

```
$(function() {
    $("#block").mouseenter(
    function(){
        $("#block").transition({ x: '+=90px', backgroundColor: '#cacaca', color: '#000' }, 1000 );
    });

    $("#block").mouseleave(
    function(){
         $("#block").transition({ x: '-=90px', backgroundColor: '#036', color: '#fff'  }, 500 );
    });
});
```